# Dates where only year is known (e.g. 1570-00-00)

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a database table with a field named Born (type = date) that features people's birth dates (e.g. 1970-07-08). But what do I do with people whose birthdays aren't precisely known?

For example, one historical figure was born in 1570. So I put this in my database: 1570-00-00. But it displays November 30, 1569.

This is the code I'm using, where $Born is a date stored in the database...

```
$Born = $row['Born'];

$Birth = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $Born);
```

My question should be answered @ [Storing a date where only the year may be known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416978/storing-a-date-where-only-the-year-may-be-known) but I'm confused. It sounds like there are several options, and I'm not sure which would be the best choice in my case.

It seems like it would be simple to just separate the month and day from year. So I'd have a field named Year (type = year) and another field named Date for the month and day. But can I set the latter up as a "date" field and insert values like 01-01 (for January 1), or do I have to insert the complete date (e.g. 1570-01-01), then insert the year alone in the Year field?

To put it another way, here are two ways I could store the date April 5, 1970 in a database table:

Year | Date
1970 | 04-05
1970 | 1970-04-05

If I'm going to put the date in two separate fields, then the first method would probably be simplest. Or is there a better way of doing it?

And here's how I could store a date that consists of a year only:

1988 | 1988-00-00

My query and display script would just extract 1988 from the Year field and ignore every value consisting of a double zero (00); in other words, it would ignore the second field (Date).

I've also thought about changing the field holding values for years from "year" to "integer," because I get "out of range value" errors for older years.

Because of all the confusion, I'm actually thinking of creating three fields - Year, Month and Day - and just displaying "plain English" values, like this:

1970 | January | 10

Would that be an OK solution, or would I suffer some significant performance hit?

Comment: Maybe you could just have a range. Earliest and Latest date. In the cases where the birth of date is known for sure these values would be the same.

Comment: You might not have a performance hit, but you'd sure complicate any queries where you needed to filter by dates, sort by dates, group by dates, or do anything else meaningful with dates. (Depending on your DBMS, you could also have a performance hit. Any time you're asking about your database, include at least a tag that indicates what database you're using - a proper answer sometimes depends on that information.)

Comment: Good tip, Ken; I should have said I'm working with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: I've added those tags to your question. BTW, interpreting 1570-00-00 as Nov 30, 1569 makes some sense; it's one month and one day before 1570-01-01.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a full date "`1570-01-01`" and add a boolean field  `IsExactDate` set to False in the cases where you don't know the exact date. In fact, I'd add a default value on `IsExactDate`  and set it to be `True`. That way you only have to set it explictly when adding a non-exact date.

You could take it further with something like 3 extra fields `IsExactYear`, `IsExactMonth`, `IsExactDayDate` for modelling historical dates of limited accuracy.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. What's a boolean field? It sounds like you're suggesting I add a new field named "IsExactDate" to my database table, right? But how do you set it to "False"?

Comment: well, it depends on the RDBMS but in SQL Server a boolean field is a bit field with zero (0) being False.

Comment: Or you could add a filed that indicates the precision of the date (year, month, or day). (You can't use the [MySQL `YEAR` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/year.html) because it only goes back to 1901.)

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, the [answer by Mitch Wheat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21198827/642706) is interesting.

On the other hand, you are trying to shove a square peg into a round hole. A [DATE in SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Date_and_time) is a year+month+day. But for these historical figures, you don't have a month or day, only a year. And even then the year may be only approximate.

In my experience of designing and maintaining database-backed systems, jerry-rigging or hacking the data always ends up backfiring eventually. in the long run it always pays off to "tell the truth".

By that I mean that in this case, the truth is **you simply don't have a birthdate for some people**. You have an approximate & partial birthdate, just a year or a year and month. A partial date does not make a `DATE` SQL value. So if you don't have a DATE value, don't use a DATE field/column.

In your case I would have two fields/columns:

- `known_birthdate_` (DATE) [or perhaps `precise_birthdate_`]
- `approximate_birthdate_` (VARCHAR)

---

Regarding, your idea for separate year, month, and day fields… That may or may not make sense. Depends on your business problem.

Your question fails to say what your goals are, what you intend to do with the data. Are you trying to find people born before or after certain dates? Are you gathering up historical figures to be grouped by Century? Do you want to calculate people's ages? For those with unknown or imprecise birth dates, how should they be handled? If you spell out the business logic and rules, your data structure may reveal itself.

Comment: I agree, Mitch Wheat probably hit the nail on the head. However, I voted for Basil's answer because it's easy for me to understand and implement. I'll just modify my code so that if there's no value in the field birthdate, it will instead extract a value from the field approximate_birthdate.

Comment: storing dates as varchar almost always leads to unanticipated problems later on.

Comment: @MitchWheat Mitch, we're talking about storing *non-dates* in *non-DATE* fields. Agreed, a true date value should be stored in a DATE or TIMESTAMP (etc.) column, to enforce integrity of the value. But for these cases where he does not really know a date (year+month+date), I suggest *not* trying to squeeze that not-really-a-date thingie into a DATE data type column. For those non-dates, text (VARCHAR) is appropriate. If calculating an age, or sorting by the birthdate is more important than accuracy, then your answer is appropriate. As I said, David didn't fully spell out his needs.

Comment: It's still a kind of date. By storing an approximate date and indicators to that effect, the problem pretty much goes away. If you only know a year (say 1570), then storing as 1570-01-01 with a flag of IsExactYear = True and IsExactMonth = False, IsExactDayDate = False  is in no way  'jerry rigging or hacking' or 'not telling the truth'. We are not attempting to make the date any more precise by supplying the  month and year 1570-01-01. And any system consuming this info is free to interpret the date as it sees fit.